# How to view full bounce message in mutt?

Tags: email, mutt

I got an error when sending email with mutt , some "red" text shows at the bottom of terminal , how should I view the full error message ? Is there a shortcut / macro that I could use / define ?

Answer (score 1):

In command line`:`
`exec error-history`

Answer (score -1):

Use good old `tee`. For example:

```
mutt 2>&1 | tee /tmp/mutt.log
```

Then examine `/tmp/mutt.log`

Comment: Wouldn't that perhaps enable scroll-back access to the status line text, but *not* the full bounce error if that wasn't already shown in the status bar?

Answer (score -1):

Neomutt has function `show-log-message` which is bound by default to `M`. Unfortunately mutt doesn't have it.